# declared variable in angular for script is not recognized when run in unit test

Tags: javascript, angular

I added a script in index.html
`<script src="https://sample.com/newScript.js"></script>`

And for it to be used in my component,
I declared its variable in my component.

`declare var NewScriptVariable: any;`

Which I could now use `NewScriptVariable.addCard` in my component.
The problem now is when creating a unit test,
it does not recognize the `NewScriptVariable`.

I get this error `ReferenceError: NewScriptVariable is not defined`

Any idea what should be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I now found the solution.
You have to download the script and add it in your local.

In your `karma.conf.js` add the file under the config.

```
config.set({

    files: [
        '/file/location.here.js'
    ]
```